# jquery datepicker not working for dynamic rows

Tags: jquery-ui, dynamic, html-table, jquery-ui-datepicker

I looked at many solutions, but this did not help.
I am a newbie to JQuery.

I want to bind a date picker to the newly added row in a table.
The script file is as follows.

```
$('a.add-passenger').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        counter++;
        var newRow = 
            '<tr>' + 
                '<td><input type="text" name="Name' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="DOB' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="PassNum' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="PassExpiry' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="Destination' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="DepDate' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><input type="text" name="ArrDate' + counter + '"/></td>' +
                '<td><a class="remove">remove</a></td>'
            '</tr>';
        $table.append(newRow);

        $( "DOB" ).datepicker( "destroy" );
        $("#DOB").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
        });

        $("#ArrDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#DepDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
            }
        });

        $("#DepDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
            $("#ArrDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
            }
        });

    });
```

However, when the row is added, only the first row has the date pickers and not the other rows.
There are different date pickers and hence I cannot use a class for date pickers.

Comment: Please post a fiddle

Comment: Please find attached. https://jsfiddle.net/5baa5sct/